# How can I have a wordpress post doing 302 redirect on some metadata?

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

I am writing a wordpress plugin that adds a new post type.
This post type can have a metadata called "redirect". When redirect is populated, I'd like to get a 302 redirect to the URL written in that field, instead of showing the post.

I've tried die(), exit(), wp_die() with headers() but it always shows "headers already sent".

Now I'm trying to hook to "send_headers", but at this level I don't have the post ID or the post metadata.

Any suggestions on where to hook to be able to do a proper 302 redirect instead of showing the post?

Note: I would like not to touch the theme, so my plugin can be theme-indipendent

Thanks

Comment: there are already plugins that do this, download one and see how they are doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
add_action( "template_redirect", "callback_function_name");

function callback_function_name(){
  global $post;
  // https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags
 // check single custom post type
  if( is_singular("post_typename")){  
    echo $post->ID; // write redirection code here
    exit;
  } 
}
```

Comment: wow! that's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much